# perl programming to store column value based on another column value

Tags: perl

i have an input in text file like :

```
Time(1ps)  *_sysclock *hy_dvdd_0 *y_vdd18_0 *s_enabled *lpi_clk_0
========== ========== ========== ========== ========== ==========
1000000000 1          1          1          11         1         
1000000045 1          1          1          11         0         
1000008365 1          1          1          11         1         
1000009824 0          1          1          11         1         
1000016685 0          1          1          11         0         
1000025005 0          1          1          11         1         
1000033325 0          1          1          11         0         
1000035828 1          1          1          11         0         
1000041645 1          1          1          11         1         
1000049965 1          1          1          11         0         
1000058285 1          1          1          11         1         
1000061832 0          1          1          11         1         
1000066605 0          1          1          11         0
```

What i have to do here is : 
2nd column indicate the clock edge and first column indicate the time.. I need to measure the clock frequency. 
so what my requirement is, since this script is taking the first value as depend on the time when i run the script, so when clock value changes from initial value, in the above example initial value is 1, so when it changes to 0, that time i want to store the column 1 value in one variable and when again clock value changes to 1 that time i want to store the column 1 value to get the clock pulse duration.

based on that i want to compare these timing difference with some predefined value to compare it.

can you experts help me in solving this.

thanks all in advance.

Expected O/P is : 
I need the output which tells me the difference between the edges.. like in the above example : 
diff between "1000009824" where the first changes in the clock edge occurs. and 
 "1000061832" where the clock edge value again comes a 0, means a full clock cycle.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please edit the question to add the output that you expect from the example input, and also add the Perl code you have tried so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose you have your input coming in on STDIN. You might want to ignore the first two lines:

```
<> for 1..2;
```

Then, you can read in a line of data:

```
my $line = <>;                   #read line from STDIN
my @initial = split(' ', $line);  #split on whitespace
```

You can read more lines in until you see a change:

```
my @final;
while ($line = <>) {
    @final = split(' ', $line);
    last if $final[1] != $initial[1];
}
```

And now you can compare the timestamps:

```
my $diff = $final[0] - $initial[0];
print "$initial[0] to $final[0] is $diff\n";
```

I'd recommend reading the line into a hash, so you have real column names instead of array indices... but that's up to you.

Comment: hi i tried your code, what is happening now.. i am getting the output like "1000000000 to 1000009824 is 9824" this is correct.. but my requirement was to find out the difference between time "1000009824 " and "1000061832 " basically a clock pulse.

Comment: @Pankaj Kumar: rutter has given you all the parts you need, but it is short of coding your answer for you - something that is discouraged on SO, because this is not a free code solutions service, it is a place for *you* to learn to solve code problems. Do you know enough Perl to write a loop, and repeat the above code twice (to find two changes)?

Comment: @NeilSlater : i know very well that SO is not for free code service.. i tried my best to get the code done and its already done.. the only reason i asked Rutter because i thought he didnt understand my requirement. anyways thanks a lot for the help.